# What is the exact location SharePointProjectItem.spdata file in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint, namespaces

What is the exact location of **SharePointProjectItem.spdata** file in **SharePoint 2007 and SharePoint 2010?**

I know the file is a hidden file. I tried searching hidden files but couldn't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.spdata files are part of Visual Studio 2010 SharePoint projects: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee710181.aspx

To best of my knowledge they aren't deployed to SharePoint 2010 servers and they definitely don't get deployed to SP2007 because VS2010 SharePoint projects were designed with SP2010 in mind.

Comment: You are right. But I'm working with SharePoint 2007 project. My webpart project is just a Class Library. Really I didn't find the file. I was finding that file to modify because I was receiving some error due changes of namespace in my webpart control.